# How to make sure the function is executed in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm trying to execute 3 functions, and after than console.log the values that they change. I think there should be better approach for this kind of problems, but I'm not sure what it is. What I've done is I went old school, and added loading flag. Basically, `loading = 3`, when function is loaded, `loading--`

I'd like to demonstrate my current code *(well actually it's not the same, but it will work for demo purposes)*, so you can get the feeling:

```
data:() => ({
  loading: 3,
  first: null,
  second: null,
  third: null
}),

methods: {
  first() {
    this.$route.get('/data/for/first').then(response => {
      this.first = response.data;
      this.loading--;
    })
  },
  second() {
    this.$route.get('/data/for/second').then(response => {
     this.second = response.data;
     this.loading--;
    })
  },
  third() {
    this.$route.get('/data/for/third/a').then(responseA => {
      let thirdA = responseA.data;
      this.$route.get('/data/for/third/b').then(responseB => {
        let thirdB = responseB.data;

        if (thirdA === thirdB) {
          this.third = true;
        }

        this.loading--;
      })
    })
  },
  fireFunctions() {
    this.first();
    this.second();
    this.third();
  }
},

watch: {
  loading: function() {
      if (this.loading === 0) {
          console.log(this.first, this.second, this.third)
      }
   }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
dataForFirst, dataForSecond, dataForThird;
```

But, if I don't use the watcher, and load this.fireFunctions() in mounted() i get:

```
dataForFirst, dataForSecond, undefined;
```

Now, as I understand, this is happening because this.third() needs more time to process the data. As you can see in the code, I added loading flag. So, fire functions will only execute when all of the functions are loaded.
I don't think this is the best approach, so I'd like to hear your opinion on this one.

How would you handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait on all your async functions to return and then run whatever code you need to afterward, example:

```
methods: {
  async all() {
    let [first, second, third] = await Promise.all([
      this.$route.get('/data/for/first'),
      this.$route.get('/data/for/second'),
      this.$route.get('/data/for/third')
    ]);
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
    this.third = third;
    console.log(first, second, third);
  }
}
```